# Chromedriver not loading in time. Gives error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

I have written some automation scripts to download data from websites. I am using Selenium webdriver libraries and Chromedriver. and I have created runnable jars for each script and have scheduled them. Whenever scripts run on remote desktop, most of the time i am getting this error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
>   server to start.

This exception is thrown on the line

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

So is there any way to increase the wait time for chromedriver to launch so that this issue may not occur. Or any other reason this issue is happening. I am using latest chromedriver version 2.34

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Have you set properties to your Chromedriver?

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: yes i have set properties
This is not occuring everytime
mostly when 3-4 chromedriver are invokes simulatenously

Comment: hi, I'm also facing this issue. Is there any way to change the time set for the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

How about implicityWait? Have you set?

```
 wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Another custom solution you can try to add Thread.sleep.. but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to [Run multiple instances of Selenium driver in same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182807/run-multiple-instances-of-selenium-driver-in-same-machine)

- If you try to run the multiple scripts at the same time, use
  threading with multiple instances of Web Driver.
- Use driver.quit properly. See https://www.mkyong.com/selenium/many-chromedriver-exe-are-left-hanging-on-windows-selenium/